# what is hard delete and soft delete in Nexus3

Tags: nexus, nexus3, nexus3-api

Can someone help me to understand what is hard delete and soft delete in nexus, since I am bit confuse

if I delete something from Nexus3 GUI I can still see blob count as same, and when I run clean up task then only it gets reflected.

also wanted to know
we have one shell script which gives us blobstore name, bucket repo name and sha value from .properties file, is there any way we can delete multiple at once without login to GUI.

Please help to understand above two scenario

Regards,

Samurai

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NXRM2 had the concept of a "trash" system, so when you deleted it it wasn't gone forever, you needed to clear the trash for it to be gone.

In NXRM3, there is no "trash" (as of 3.29.0 anyway) however the concept is the same.  When you delete something from NXRM3 GUI, it "soft delete"s the component so if something was accidentally deleted it could be recovered.  Specifically, the associated blob in the database is flagged for deletion.
If you run the compact blobstore scheduled task, it looks for all "soft delete"d items and deletes them.  That is the "hard delete", there is no recovery from this besides a restore from backup.

You should be able to delete without using the GUI using the [REST API](https://help.sonatype.com/display/NXRM3/REST+and+Integration+API), but I suggest another question for that as it would need more detail to answer (in my opinion).